# Check for internet access with monotouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

How can I check internet access with MonoTouch? I don't care if the internet comes from a WIFI or the Cell Network, all I care is whether there is internet access or not.

Comment: The above link to the Reachabiity class has been moved to the following: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using Miguel's Reachability class (found here: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs) you can just call it like this:

```
if(!Reachability.IsHostReachable("http://google.com")) {
    // Put alternative content/message here
}
else
{
    // Put Internet Required Code here
}
```

Hope this helps,

ChrisNTR

Comment: Thanks, chisntr. So far this has worked on the simulator. Will update if i run into problems with the real hardware.

Comment: I've got an app up on the AppStore using the same code and seems to work on all devices, if you run in to any problems then let me know.

Comment: Hi ChrisNTR: I believe static classes can't be instantiateed, so I: - removed the instantiation - replaced the if statement with: **if(!Reachability.IsHostReachable("www.bestwebbuys.com"))** It now works for me...

Comment: I've updated the link - but now the sample code won't run as the class has gone static (sorry!) - won't be hard for people to work out though!

Comment: @chrisntr: The class seems to have issues when calling its InternetConnectionStatus(). In airplane/flight mode, it will always return Wifi

Comment: @skarmats : The issue with InternetConnectionStatus() should now be fixed in github.

Comment: The method IsHostReachable requires a host, so the example code should be: `if(!Reachability.IsHostReachable("google.com"))`, without the http prefix.