# iphone monotouch detect if there is an internet connection

Tags: iphone, connection, xamarin.ios

In Monotouch on an iPhone/iPod, how do I detect if there is an internet connection available?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961341/check-for-internet-access-with-monotouch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way right now is to use this class from Miguel de Icaza's GitHub repository:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs

Its a static class with a lot of methods, so all you have to do is add it to your project and call, for example:

```
NetworkStatus status = Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus();
```